# .Htaccess Mod rewrite file.php to file.xml?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have come unstuck with a job im doing that requires some flash xml vars to be loaded by ajax, but I have to generate the xml file with php and for some reason it breaks when i try to jquery load it, but when i changed the extention from php to xml and it worked.

Now I would like to use mod rewrite to rewrite

```
settings.php?id=1
```

to

```
/1/settings.xml
```

ive been trying to do it myself using tutorials but i just cant get it right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: edited your tags, as it is not PHP related

Comment: Why dont you simply get the id parameter from the $GET in php and then form the corresponding xml url and redirect. If this solution is enough, let me know, I will post the code

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^settings.php?id=(.*) $1/settings.xml [L]

Comment: RewriteBase might not be mandatory though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to use mod rewrite to rewrite `settings.php?id=1` to `/1/settings.xml`

which means this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)\.php$ /%1/$1.xml [L]
```

So when someone requests `http://domain.com/settings.php?id=1`, they get served the content at `/1/settings.xml`, but if it's the other way around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)\.xml /settings.php?id=1 [L,QSA]
```

So a request for `http://domain.com/1/settings.xml` will get served the content at `/settings.php?id=1`

Since it's never clear what "rewrite `<uri>` to `<another uri>`" ever means.

Comment: @TommyArnold sorry, mispelled `RewriteEngine`

Comment: Thanks, i need to load the contents of settings.php?id=5 by accessing the url /5/settings.xml but the first code block you posted is giving a 404 error

Comment: @TommyArnold if you want to get served the contents of `settings.php?id=5` then you want the second rule.